# Rails find_or_create_by using a default value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement a very basic auth for my JS/Rails application where a user would enter a username and rails would either sign in the user with that username, or create a new user with said username. The problem with this is that my User model has a balance attribute which is automatically set to null by rails upon instantiation. For reference;

**User Class**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
has_many :strategies
validates :username, presence: true
validates :username, uniqueness: true
end
```

**Users Controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
    render json: UserSerializer.new(@users)
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_or_create_by(username: params[:username])
    render json: user, except: [:created_at, :updated_at]
  end
end
```

I tried changing my create action in my Users Controller to this

```
def create
    user = User.find_or_create_by(username: params[:username], balance = 1000)
    render json: user, except: [:created_at, :updated_at]
end
```

I want to tell rails to set the balance to 1000 **ONLY** if being created **BUT** it also uses the default balance to find users which is an issue for me. **How can I set the default balance value for creating a user however let it be ignored when "find"ing a user?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
User.find_or_create_by(username: params[:username]) do |user|
  user.balance = 1000
end
```

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what I was looking for!!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code?

```
User.create_with(balance: 1000)
    .find_or_create_by(username: params[:username])
```

Comment: It is strange.

`
# Find the first user named "Scarlett" or create a new one with
# a particular last name.
User.create_with(last_name: 'Johansson').find_or_create_by(first_name: 'Scarlett')
`

Source https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by